# Highlighting navbar list when element is in viewport using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

I want to change the background of list elements in nav bar when i scroll into a specific section in the body only using vanilla JavaScript... i have made a function that checks the ViewPort but i am having difficulty putting listener for each HTML Element in the collection. can anyone help?

```js
/* VARIABLES */
const newSectionBtn = document.getElementById("new-section");
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const backBtn = document.getElementById("back");
let allLists = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
let allSections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
let n = 4;

/* FUNCTIONS */
function duplicate(num) {
  const newSection = document.createElement("section");
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const heading = document.createElement("h2");
  const p1 = document.createElement("p");
  const p2 = document.createElement("p");

  newSection.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(heading);
  newDiv.appendChild(p1);
  newDiv.appendChild(p2);

  newSection.setAttribute("id", "section" + num);
  newSection.setAttribute("data-nav", "Section" + " " + num);
  newDiv.setAttribute("class", "landing__container");

  heading.textContent = "Section" + " " + num;
  p1.textContent =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.";
  p2.textContent =
    "Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.";

  return newSection;
}


/* LISTENERS */
newSectionBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  newSectionBtn.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<li> Section" + " " + n + "</li>");
  main.appendChild(duplicate(n));
  main.lastElementChild.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
  n++;
});

backBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
});
```

```css
/*
 *
 * CSS written based on SMACSS architecture.
 * To learn more, visit: http://smacss.com/
 * 
 * For simplicity, no reset or normalize is added. 
 * To learn more, visit: https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/
 *
*/


/* ---- Base Rules ---- */

body {
  background: rgb(136, 203, 171);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(136, 203, 171, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 13, 60, 1) 100%);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Typeography General*/

h1 {
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 2em 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 7em;
    margin: 2em 4rem 1em;
  }
}

h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cc1;
  font-family: "Oxygen", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6em;
  color: #eee;
}


/* ---- Layout Rules ---- */

main {
  margin: 10vh 1em 10vh;
}

.main-hero {
  min-height: 40vh;
  padding-top: 3em;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 80vh;
}


/* ---- Module Rules ---- */


/* Navigation Styles*/

.navbar__menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar__menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease 0.3s all;
}


/* Header Styles */

.page__header {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}


/* Footer Styles */

.page__footer {
  background: #000;
  padding: 3em;
  color: #fff;
}

.page__footer p {
  color: #fff;
}


/* ---- Theme Rules ---- */


/* Landing Container Styles */

.landing__container {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  .landing__container {
    max-width: 50em;
    padding: 4em;
  }
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}


/* Background Circles */


/* Note that background circles are created with psuedo elements before and after */


/* Circles appear to be random do to use of :nth-of-type psuedo class */

section:nth-of-type(odd) .landing__container::before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.187);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container::before {
  content: "";
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  right: 3em;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n) .landing__container::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n + 1) .landing__container::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 20vw;
  bottom: -5em;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 15vh;
  height: 15vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}


/* ---- Theme State Rules ---- */


/* Section Active Styles */


/* Note: your-active-class class is applied through javascript. You should update the class here and in the index.html to what you set in your javascript file.  */

section.your-active-class {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}

section.your-active-class .landing__container::before {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

section.your-active-class .landing__container::after {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite forwards reverse;
}


/* Section Active Styles Keyframe Animations */

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-1em) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-1em) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}


/* MY STYLES */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #00c3c7;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 100px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-self: center;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: darkred;
  font-size: 100px;
}

JavaScript:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Manipulating the DOM</title>
  <!-- Load Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Load Styles -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
 IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
      <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main id="main">
    <header class="main__hero">
      <nav>
        <ul class="flex-container">
          <li>Section 1</li>
          <li>Section 2</li>
          <li>Section 3</li>
          <li id="new-section">NEW SECTION</li>
          <li id="back">BACK TO TOP</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1>Landing Page</h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Each Section has an ID (used for the anchor) and 
   a data attribute that will populate the li node.
   Adding more sections will automatically populate nav.
   The first section is set to active class by default -->
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed
          convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor
          lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.
        </p>

        <p>
          Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor
          tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed
          convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor
          lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.
        </p>

        <p>
          Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor
          tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed
          convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor
          lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.
        </p>

        <p>
          Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor
          tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="page__footer">
    <p>&copy Udacity</p>
  </footer>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I always use aos for "animate on scroll" animations and its pretty simple.

Comment: https://github.com/michalsnik/aos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

[References](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/) Read the link on how the `isInViewport` function work.

The for each part I added to work on multiple elements. The if parts condition when to do something.

```
        var isInViewport = function(elem) {
          var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
          return (
            distance.top >= 0 &&
            distance.left >= 0 &&
            distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
            distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
          );
        };
    // read the link on how above code works
     
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
// add event on scroll
  var findMe = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
  var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
// on scroll fetch H2 and li elements, on scroll in order to get new dynamically added with button
  findMe.forEach(element => {
//for each h2
    if (isInViewport(element)) {
//if in Viewport
        li.forEach(li => {
          li.style.color = 'white';
        })
//set all li styles to none in order to remove before added
        li.forEach(li => {
//for each li
          if (li.innerHTML.trim() === element.innerHTML.trim()) {
//if li text is same as curent element in viport text 
            li.style.color = 'red';
//add style
          }
        })
    }
  });
}, false);
```

For some reason It does not work for section, or wrapping div, it works on elements with content inside.

So you need to target H2 elements, and make conditions.

**Example:**

```js
/* VARIABLES */
const newSectionBtn = document.getElementById("new-section");
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const backBtn = document.getElementById("back");
let allLists = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
let allSections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
let n = 4;

/* FUNCTIONS */
function duplicate(num) {
  const newSection = document.createElement("section");
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const heading = document.createElement("h2");
  const p1 = document.createElement("p");
  const p2 = document.createElement("p");

  newSection.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(heading);
  newDiv.appendChild(p1);
  newDiv.appendChild(p2);

  newSection.setAttribute("id", "section" + num);
  newSection.setAttribute("data-nav", "Section" + " " + num);
  newDiv.setAttribute("class", "landing__container");

  heading.textContent = "Section" + " " + num;
  p1.textContent =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.";
  p2.textContent =
    "Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.";

  return newSection;
}


/* LISTENERS */
newSectionBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  newSectionBtn.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<li> Section" + " " + n + "</li>");
  main.appendChild(duplicate(n));
  main.lastElementChild.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
  n++;
});

backBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
});


var isInViewport = function(elem) {
  var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    distance.top >= 0 &&
    distance.left >= 0 &&
    distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
};


window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  var findMe = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
  var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  findMe.forEach(element => {
    if (isInViewport(element)) {
        li.forEach(li => {
          li.style.color = 'white';
        })
        li.forEach(li => {
          if (li.innerHTML.trim() === element.innerHTML.trim()) {
            li.style.color = 'red';
          }
        })
    }
  });
}, false);
```

```css
/*
 *
 * CSS written based on SMACSS architecture.
 * To learn more, visit: http://smacss.com/
 * 
 * For simplicity, no reset or normalize is added. 
 * To learn more, visit: https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/
 *
*/


/* ---- Base Rules ---- */

body {
  background: rgb(136, 203, 171);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(136, 203, 171, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 13, 60, 1) 100%);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Typeography General*/

h1 {
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 2em 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 7em;
    margin: 2em 4rem 1em;
  }
}

h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cc1;
  font-family: "Oxygen", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6em;
  color: #eee;
}


/* ---- Layout Rules ---- */

main {
  margin: 10vh 1em 10vh;
}

.main-hero {
  min-height: 40vh;
  padding-top: 3em;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 80vh;
}


/* ---- Module Rules ---- */


/* Navigation Styles*/

.navbar__menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar__menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease 0.3s all;
}


/* Header Styles */

.page__header {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}


/* Footer Styles */

.page__footer {
  background: #000;
  padding: 3em;
  color: #fff;
}

.page__footer p {
  color: #fff;
}


/* ---- Theme Rules ---- */


/* Landing Container Styles */

.landing__container {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  .landing__container {
    max-width: 50em;
    padding: 4em;
  }
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}


/* Background Circles */


/* Note that background circles are created with psuedo elements before and after */


/* Circles appear to be random do to use of :nth-of-type psuedo class */

section:nth-of-type(odd) .landing__container::before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.187);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container::before {
  content: "";
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  right: 3em;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n) .landing__container::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n + 1) .landing__container::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 20vw;
  bottom: -5em;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 15vh;
  height: 15vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}


/* ---- Theme State Rules ---- */


/* Section Active Styles */


/* Note: your-active-class class is applied through javascript. You should update the class here and in the index.html to what you set in your javascript file.  */

section.your-active-class {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}

section.your-active-class .landing__container::before {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

section.your-active-class .landing__container::after {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite forwards reverse;
}


/* Section Active Styles Keyframe Animations */

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-1em) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-1em) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}


/* MY STYLES */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #00c3c7;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 100px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-self: center;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: darkred;
  font-size: 100px;
}

JavaScript:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Manipulating the DOM</title>
  <!-- Load Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Load Styles -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
 IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
      <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main id="main">
    <header class="main__hero">
      <nav>
        <ul class="flex-container">
          <li>Section 1</li>
          <li>Section 2</li>
          <li>Section 3</li>
          <li id="new-section">NEW SECTION</li>
          <li id="back">BACK TO TOP</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1>Landing Page</h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Each Section has an ID (used for the anchor) and 
   a data attribute that will populate the li node.
   Adding more sections will automatically populate nav.
   The first section is set to active class by default -->
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed
          convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor
          lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.
        </p>

        <p>
          Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor
          tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed
          convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor
          lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.
        </p>

        <p>
          Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor
          tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed
          convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor
          lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.
        </p>

        <p>
          Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor
          tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="page__footer">
    <p>&copy Udacity</p>
  </footer>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem with your code..  i have ( add new section button ).. and it will add a lot of sections depend on the user needs... and it is hard to make ( else if ) statement for every one of them. how can i do it with a lot of sections up to 20 sections maybe...

Comment: @FAHAD Sorry my bad I missed that, I made edits and its working now with added sections as seen in snippet. Basically you match  `li` `innerHTML` with `h2` `innerHTML` on scroll. It will work now on any number of sections.

Comment: Thank you so much, WORKS FINE!

Comment: @FAHAD Great, please consider to mark this answer as accepted on ✔︎  ,to mark it as solved for others. Welcome to SO.